# Javascript dice game

Tags: javascript

I have written the code below where the dice face is supposed to change the dice image based on the random number generated. If I used the google development tools and console.log, I can see the random number is generated and even the scr is replaced but the image does not change. They are in a different folder called images. What could be the problem ?

Code:

```
var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
console.log(randomNumber1);

var randomDiceImage = "images/dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";
console.log(randomDiceImage);

document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("scr", randomDiceImage);
```

Html:

```
<div class="dice">
     <p>Player 1</p>
     <img class="img1" src="images/dice1.png" />
</div>
```

> the result after running the code.

`<img class="img1" src="images/dice6.png" scr="images/dice2.png">`

Comment: I think you've misspelled `src` as `scr`

Comment: scr should be src in your set-attribute :-) And in your html as well (there is no attribute called scr for image-elements)

Comment: Hi,thanks I just saw it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to set "src" not "scr". Try to set the SRC instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
//differentiate the dice image and dice source column
let randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
var randomDiceImage = "dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";
var randomImageSource = "images/" + randomDiceImage;
var image1 = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];
image1.setAttribute("src", randomImageSource);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).